# С помощью какой технологии сделаны прикрепляемые окошки wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно сделать открепляемые и прикрепляемые окошки на wpf C# как в студии. Иначе говоря что бы можно было открепить панель от основного окна или же расположить ее слева/по центру/справа и тому подобное. При помощи какой технологии это делается ? Я ранее не делал подобного.

Comment: Название этому `MDI`, в WPF есть например `AvalonDock`, с помощью которого можно легко сделать подобный интерфейс.

Comment: я даже могу кинуть пару примеров - [раз](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2011/12/avalonedit-avalondock.html) ([исходники](https://github.com/tym32167/dotnetnotepad)), [два](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient)

Comment: Благодарю всех)